# How do I import user defined variable without creating infinite loop

Tags: python, import

I keep on getting into a loop when trying to use a user-defined variable in another script. But after spending a long time tinkering I can't a way around it and am wondering what I'm doing wrong. My first script (***STACK_1***) is a GUI in which the user choices options from a checkbox:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
import os

class MyApp(object):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        self.root = parent
        self.root.title("Main frame")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()

        close_btn = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Close Application", command=self.closeApplication)
        close_btn.pack()

        global lb

        lb = tk.Listbox(self.root, selectmode = "multiple")
        lb.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

        x =["Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3"]

        for item in range(len(x)):
            lb.insert(tk.END, x[item])
            lb.itemconfig(item, bg="#ffffff")

        tk.Button(self.root, text="Confirm Choices", command=self.confirmSelected).place(relx=0.205, rely=0.62)

        Executefile_btn = tk.Button(self.root, text="Run main file", command=self.runfile)
        Executefile_btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9)

    def closeApplication(self):
        self.root.destroy()

    def runfile(self):
        os.system('python STACK_3.py')

    def confirmSelected(self):
        planets = []
        cname = lb.curselection()
        for i in cname:
            op = lb.get(i)
            planets.append(op)
            self.planets = planets
        for val in planets:
            print(val)
        if len(planets) < 2:
            print("At least two choices need to be selected")
        return planets
```

my second script (***STACK_2***) initialises the other class and forms the GUI itself & saves the list of variables chosen by the user:

```
import STACK_1
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("N Body Simulation")
root.geometry('400x300')
app = STACK_1.MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()

planets = app.planets
```

my third script (***STACK_3***) just prints the list out generated through scripts 1 & 2:

```
from STACK_2 import planets

print(planets)
```

However, it keeps looping, as more and more GUI's get produced as script 3 imports script 2 and hence runs it. However, I don't see a way of not importing script 2. In addition, the print function works only on the subsequent GUI's produced and never the first. I don't understand the latter behaviour nor a way to accomplish this without importing script 2. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should really understand, `global planets` does *nothing* inside your `class MyApp(object):` block... what did you *expect* it to do?

Comment: You are totally right, that was there from when I was playing around to see what worked. I have removed it now. I believe I did it to save it as a variable in the same script but outside the class, so that it could be imported from another script. But that didn't work.

Comment: why are you importing `STACK_1` inside `STACK_3`? This is not needed. Importing `planets` from `STACK_2` will be enough

Comment: apologies that was an artefact from when I was trying to import planets directly from STACK_1 to STACK_3, I have now removed it but that is irrelevant to the looping problem isn't it?

Comment: when you use import from STACK_2 import planets, it just launches the GUI again, because everything on STACK_2.py is on main. to avoid that, you must put the code in STACK_2.py after checking if __name__ == '__main__':...    but that should give you an error, because you can not import the variable planets. that variable is user defined, yes, but the STACK_2.py file will not change itself, I think you should use an extra file or something for saving the planets variable.

Comment: For the extra script won't the same problem be encountered as ```STACK_3```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with this script, but the underlying issue that causes infinite windows to be created is in the STACK_1.py.

This issue can be resolved by changing two of your functions inside this file.

```
def closeApplication(self):
    self.root.destroy()

def runfile(self):
    os.system('python STACK_3.py')
```

Firstly, as it seems the program is already being run from STACK_3, when runfile is called, STACK_3 will be called again, which calls STACK_2, which reinitialises the GUI.

Instead, if we just replace this function with

```
def runfile(self):
    self.root.destroy()
```

This is now the same however as the closeApplication function. If your intentions are for the closeApplication function to completely finish the program, you'd need to reflect this as otherwise it will still attempt to print planets, which is an empty list (note also I included an assignment for self.planets in the MyApp init as this is standard and also prevents an error being thrown when planets is attempted to print but doesn't exist.)

```
def close_application(self):
    self.root.destroy()
    exit()
```

Also be sure to use the [PEP8 standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) for naming functions.

All this is assuming that the script is run from STACK_3.py. If it isn't, why include STACK_3.py at all, just add the print line after everything in STACK_2.py and the script will still run the same if these changes are inlcuded.

Comment: Oh ok, that's amazing, thank you very much. The misconception I had is that I for some reason thought that I had to have GUI open, the whole time. So I hadn't thought of ```runfile``` just closing the app which would continue the script. Thanks again!

Comment: The reason why I implemented STACK_3 is that when I used the ```print()``` function in ```STACK_2``` it didn't work. In hindsight, this is a problem with spyder because although it doesn't work there it works perfectly in VScode.